# Location Parse Help Please

Tags: ios

I succeeded has to get back the position of the user and I also managed to get back the position of all the restaurants ( GeoPoint un data cloud Parse) my question is now to know how to compare the position of the user with that of restaurants to have the distance in kilometer?

I find this in documentation Parse

```
- (void)whereKey:(NSString *)key nearGeoPoint: (PFGeoPoint *)geopoint withinKilometers: (double)maxDistance
```

But where I can insert this?

Comment: Should be migrated to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

`Wherekey:nearGeoPoint:withInKilometers` methods mainly used for search a model (restaurant, hotel... etc) with a circle range around user's current location.
You have to get difference between user's location and restaurant. For that you have to compare both location by its lat and long.

The difference will come in degree.

- 1 degree means apx. 11 miles
- 1 miles means apx. 1.76 km .

Answer (score 1):

If you haven´t done it already, this is a great tutorial you could look in to:

https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall

And i think the code you are looking for is something like this.

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *currentLocationGeoPoint, NSError *error) { //Get current Location
    if (!error) {            
PFGeoPoint *distanceGeoPoint = [object objectForKey:@"location"];

        double distanceDouble  = [currentLocationGeoPoint distanceInKilometersTo:distanceGeoPoint];
        NSLog(@"Distance: %.1f",distanceDouble)

 }
}];
```